# pylint doesn't point to virtualenv python

Tags: python, virtualenv, pylint

I am pretty new to python and currenty I am trying to use pylint for checking code quality. I am getting a problem. My pylint doesn't point to virtualenv python interpreter. Here is the output that I get when I run pylint --version

```
 $ pylint --version
   pylint 0.21.1,
   astng 0.20.1, common 0.50.3
   Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jul 10 2013, 22:48:45)
   [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)]
```

In virtualenv I have python 2.7 installed. Will appretiate you help if someone can point me to  how to solve that.

Comment: What's the output of `which pylint` and where is your venv?

Comment: @kroolik it is /usr/bin/pylint and my virtualenv is ~/virtenvs/my_env/bin/python

Comment: Did you install pylint with your venv enabled? Once you have installed pylint using `pip install pylint` with your venv active, `which pylint` should point to `~/virtenvs/my_envs/bin/pylint`

Comment: Yes I did installed pylint with my virtenv enabled.

Comment: Have you got `~/virtenvs/my_env/bin/pylint` file?

Comment: Nope I dont have that file. So it means that there was something wrong when I installed pylint. But I am pretty sure that I did installed pylint with virtenv enabled. I enabled virtenv and then I used yum to install pylint with the following command sudu yum install pylint.

Comment: `sudo` makes so it is installed in your global env. Install it using `pip install pylint` with your venv activated.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34372/discussion-between-mirchi002-and-kroolik)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

A cheap trick is to run (the global) pylint using the virtualenv python. You can do this using `python $(which pylint)` instead of just `pylint`. On zsh, you can also do `python =pylint`.

Comment: Great, thanks. Since I use Python 3, I had to do `$(which pylint3)`.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim I just love you so much for this `=command` hack. Using zsh for quite a while now, but I never stumbled upon that one.

Comment: You're welcome luke. It's just a more succinct way of writing `$(which foo)`.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work in Vim with ALE plugin.

Comment: I don't use vim and haven't used to ALE plugin. However, if you can make your editor launch a custom script rather than the pylint directly, you can put all this stuff in there. That's why I do with my Emacs.

Comment: This didn't work for me as global packages (here pylint) are not available in venv by default. Running `python /usr/bin/pylint` gives `importlib.metadata.PackageNotFoundError: pylint` inside venv

Comment: @mpiskore I had to `pip install pylint` inside venv then close and reactive venv to get pylint working with Vim ALE.

Comment: @Hritik Then it makes no sense...

Comment: Does not work for Python 3.10

Comment: @jdhao Not surprising given how much the ecosystem has changed since 2013 which is when the answer was posted. What's the error you get?

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim I am getting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pylint'`.

Answer (score 24):

I am fairly sure that you need to install pylint under your virtual environment and then run that instance of it.

### Update - Make life easier:

I would suggest that anybody working a lot in virtual environments create a batch file, (in a known location or on the path), or bash script with something like the following called something like `getlint.bat`:

```
pip install pylint
```

Invoking this **after** activating the virtual environment will install pylint into that virtual environment. If you are likely to be offline or have a poor internet connection you can, once *when you have a good internet connection*, (possibly once for each of python 2 & 3):

```
mkdir C:\Some\Directory\You\Will\Leave\Alone
pip download --dest=C:\Some\Directory\You\Will\Leave\Alone pylint
```

Which will download pylint and its dependencies to `C:\Some\Directory\You\Will\Leave\Alone` and you can modify `getlint.bat` to read:

```
pip install pylint --find-links=C:\Some\Directory\You\Will\Leave\Alone
```

It will then use the pre-downloaded versions.

Comment: Steve is correct, I'll add that ^uninstalling^ it from your global python is also a good idea. That way you ensure you're running the correct pylint.

Comment: There goes a sad +1 since this is a real pain when using multiple (10+) virtualenvs.

Comment: @mpiskore - I have expanded the answer a little to make life easier.

Comment: I would like to add that if you created the virtualenv with `--system-site-packages` (e.g. because you use it to run your editor and don't want to debug issues with missing system packages), you may need to pass `--force-reinstall` to Pip. Alternatively `--ignore-installed` might also work, but I did not try that so I'm not sure and I cannot comment on what is better.

Answer (score 8):

[Noufal Ibrahim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17924034/4653485) works if you execute pylint manually.

If you execute pylint from you editor/IDE, you need to configure the plugin correctly.

- [vim/syntastic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23177561/4653485)
- [atom/linter-pylint](https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-pylint/issues/75)
- ...

It can get tricky. This may be considered a bug of each IDE/plugin, but that's how it is.

Modifying `/usr/bin/pylint` to write `#!/usr/bin/env python` as suggested in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23897654/4653485) fixes this for every use of pylint (manual use, or any editor integration).

However, at least in Debian, using `#!/usr/bin/python` is a [design choice](https://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/python-policy/ch-programs.html), not a bug. See [here](https://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/python-policy/ch-python.html#s-interpreter_loc) for the rationale.

To avoid modifying that system file, one can create a copy of `/usr/bin/pylint` in `/usr/local/bin`:

```
cp /usr/bin/pylint /usr/local/bin/pylint
vi usr/local/bin/pylint # Edit the file to use /usr/bin/env python
```

This won't be broken by a pylint update, but still infringes Debian's "strongly preferred choice".

This method requires root privileges. An unprivileged user may create an alias

```
alias pylint='/usr/bin/env python $(which pylint)'.
```

---

I always develop in virtualenv and I setup a postmkvirtualenv hook to install pylint and flake8 automatically when creating a virtualenv, so I don't use the versions ditributed by debian anymore.

Comment: See here for the "no use env" rationale: https://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/python-policy/ch-python.html#s-interpreter_loc

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this problem, too.  My solution was simply to edit the pylint program's shebang, like so... (your path to pylint may be different than mine, though)

```
$ sudo vim /usr/bin/pylint
```

Replacing:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

With:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Comment: Altering system programs like this for one user is not a good practice.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim Isn't this more like a bug from pylint developers that affects all of a system's users?

Comment: Nope. It's a decision by the managers of the distro to make sure that the pylint will work as advertised and is independent of your local PATH settings.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim Oh... is that so? Very educational, good man. That's a big deal to chew on. Can I ask you to submit a better answer / workaround? I get the feeling that you have a novel solution using local PATH settings.

Comment: @starlocke I don't understand what you're asking for.

Answer (score 5):

The issue has been solved on chat (link in comments).

The problem lied in using `sudo yum install pylint`, because it installed pylint in the global env. The solution was to use the following command:

`pip install -i http://f.pypi.python.org/simple pylint`

Note the `-i` usage as the regular index seemed to be broken for the asker.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's been a while since this question was answered, but I just thought I should leave this post here in case someone else runs into the same problem.

If for some reason you need to keep `pylint` in the global space instead of your virtual environment, you can use the recommendation in here: [PyLint + VirtualEnv](http://blog.algarvio.me/2012/12/27/pylint-+-virtualenv/).

It basically says to configure your `pylint` using the `init-hook` and encoding version of a Python program that will use the global `pylint` and load the rest of the environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can get there by calling the target python interpreter:

```
./env/bin/python -m pylint ...

# or in an already active env
python -m pylint ...
```

Answer (score 1):

When you're using Pipenv / virtualenv, install pylint inside the virtualenv:

```
pipenv install --dev pylint
```

or, if you don't use Pipenv, install it with pip after you activated your virtualenv:

```
# activate virtualenv, e.g. `. env/bin/activate`
pip install pylint
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the Syntastic + Pylint combination, and since I have many different virtualenvs that I can work on at any given time, I've created a wrapper over the *virtualenv* command that, among some other things, installs *pylint* after all the requirements.

That way, whenever I activate a virtualenv, I'll get its own pylint version.

Hope this helps, and thanks for the tip on deleting the global one from @briford-wylie

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same problem just today. Continuing on [ThorSummoner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1695680/thorsummoner)'s answer, when using Pylint with pylint-django inside of a virtual environment such as Pipenv, make sure to call pylint using the target python interpreter (`python -m pylint`)

A good approach, which will work locally and on your CI as well is to write-down the lint command in the script section of your Pipfile:

```
[scripts]
lint = "python -m pylint [--options] all-my-modules-names..."
```

Then calling pylint is as easy as :

```
pipenv run lint
```

Answer (score 0):

For pylint installed globally, it can not recognize the packages installed inside the virtual environment, even if we are inside the virtual env.
First, we can install [pylint-venv](https://github.com/jgosmann/pylint-venv/) in the global level (outside the virtual env):

```
pip install pylint-venv
```

Then inside the `pyproject.toml` file for this project, we can configure a init-hook for pylint:

```ini
[tool.pylint.main]
init-hook ="""
try:
  import pylint_venv
except ImportError:
  pass
else:
  pylint_venv.inithook()
"""
```

Tested on pylint 2.17, works well for me.