# Switch Python Version for Vim & Syntastic

Tags: python, vim, syntastic

Is it possible to change the python version used by syntastic for syntax checking?

As the Issue  https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/issues/385 indicates I could use virtual-env. But is it also possible just with syntastic or vim commands?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The below is no longer necessary, and might screw up if you're forced to work on a strictly python 2.x script.

The best option is to leave the Syntastic defaults alone, and to use [conda](https://conda.io/miniconda.html) to manage separate environments for python 3 and 2 (each with their own version-specific installs of flake8, pyflakes, etc), and to switch to the appropriate environment to edit each file. Syntastic will then call python/flake8/whatever else according to the paths set in the activated environment.

---

<del>From the [Syntastic repository README](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic):</del>

> #### <del>Q. The python checker complains about syntactically valid Python 3 constructs...</del>
>
> <del>A. Configure the python checker to call a Python 3 interpreter rather than Python 2, e.g:</del>
>
> <del>`let g:syntastic_python_python_exec = '/path/to/python3'`</del>

<del>Add that line to your .vimrc - that should fix your problem.</del>

Comment: Doesn't work for me, with syntastic de5e025ef0b8a9eec588d618ebaebd104945af4c.  I'm getting syntax errors from valid Python 3 constructs.  `:!python3 -m flake8 %` works fine.

Comment: @Marius Gedminas That fine, since `g:syntastic_python_python_exec` refers to the `python` checker, which is unrelated to the `flake8` checker.  If you want to run `flake8` under Python 3 either install a flake8 compiled against Python 3, or write a wrapper script, or set `g:syntastic_python_flake8_exe` (not `*_exec`, see the manual for the difference) to `'python3 -m flake8'`.

Comment: I'm now using these settings, which uses either the system `python` or the `python` defined by whatever virtualenv I'm in - I use a virtualenv for my python3 work:

`let g:syntastic_python_checkers=['pylint']`
`let g:syntastic_python_python_exec = 'python'`
`let g:syntastic_python_pylint_exe = 'python -m pylint'`

Obviously, I use `pyflakes` rather than `flake8`...

Comment: For me it makes Syntastic completely blind to any BS I hand to it.

Comment: Also, I think that this solution interferes with virtualenvs.

Comment: @BłażejMichalik: well, are you handing it the path to the virtualenv version of python? BTW, ditch virtualenv, and move to conda.

Comment: Please note that this is no longer the recommended approach these days.  Just install `virtualenv` or `pyenv`, install the relevant checkers inside, and run Vim from the virtual environment (cf. [FAQ](https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic#faqpython)). This has the advantage that it works for _all_ Python checkers, not just for `python`.

Answer (score 48):

## Easiest solution:

Add this to you **.vimrc**

```
 let g:syntastic_python_python_exec = 'python3'
 let g:syntastic_python_checkers = ['python']
```

This is the straightforward solution to switch to **python3**.

Comment: For those of us who *only* work in Python3 (especially when using Docker to contain the environment), this is much more convenient than setting up a virtual environment just to run Vim.

Comment: For virtualenv users: If you just set it as 'python', it actually works for the activated python version.

Comment: How did this get 24 upvotes if it doesn't work? There is no python checker named "python3". Adding this line will turn off all python syntax checking.

Comment: on some Linux distros python 3 executable is called "python3"

Comment: @rubystallion Thanks for the feedback. I changed the answer

Answer (score 18):

In spite of all the answers here, I still find the recommendation from the FAQ to be the best. I have added this to my `.vimrc` so that I can easily switch between python versions.

```
function Py2()
  let g:syntastic_python_python_exec = '/usr/local/bin/python2.7'
endfunction

function Py3()
  let g:syntastic_python_python_exec = '/usr/local/bin/python3.6'
endfunction

call Py3()   " default to Py3 because I try to use it when possible
```

With those functions installed, it's easy to switch python version right within vim with `:call Py2()` or `:call Py3()` depending on what I need at the moment. No need to exit vim and activate a different virtualenv as the popular answer would have you do.

Answer (score 8):

I managed to convince Syntastic to handle Python 3 syntax with

```
pip3 install --user flake8
```

(to make `python3 -m flake8 *.py` work) and then, in vim:

```
let g:syntastic_python_flake8_exec = 'python3'
let g:syntastic_python_flake8_args = ['-m', 'flake8']
```

Comment: ... Except (1) this doesn't affect the `python` checker, and (2) it makes syntastic believe flake8 is installed even when it isn't.  Set `g:syntastic_python_flake8_exe` (not `exec`) to `'python3 -m flake8'` if you insist to do it this way.

Comment: Thank you; apparently I forgot that flake8 wasn't the default Python checker in Syntastic!

Comment: You probably meant `let g:syntastic_python_flake8_exec = 'python3'`. Right?

Comment: Oops, yes, thank you!  Although today I use
`command! -bar Python2 let g:syntastic_python_flake8_exe = 'python2 -m flake8' | SyntasticCheck` and
`command! -bar Python3 let g:syntastic_python_flake8_exe = 'python3 -m flake8' | SyntasticCheck`

Comment: I'm using pyenv and this answer worked perfectly for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Not really, but you can get the `python3` incompatible warning by install
[this package](https://github.com/liamcurry/py3kwarn).

Let's say your current Syntastic Python checker is `python` and you want to get
`python3` incompatible warning. In command mode, you can add `py3kwarn` to `g:syntastic_python_checkers` by

```
:let g:syntastic_python_checkers=['python', 'py3kwarn']
```

and switch to `python2.x` only

```
:let g:syntastic_python_checkers=['python']
```

Comment: but this just works for a vim that is using python 2. I have exactly the reverse problem! Still it is a begining! thx

Comment: Upvoting because I needed to set vim to use python27, instead of the system default 26 and the accepted answer did not work.   `let g:syntastic_python_checkers=['python27']`, did.

Answer (score 3):

If you working under virtualenv, you can use a script that detects current python version and invokes `flake8` accordingly. Put the following somewhere in your path and name is `flake8.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
PYMAJOR=$(python --version | awk '{print $2}'| awk -F. '{print $1}')
exec "/usr/bin/python$PYMAJOR" /usr/bin/flake8 "$@"
```

Now in you `vimrc` add:

```
let g:syntastic_python_flake8_exe='flake8.sh'
```

Also make sure that both `python-flake8` and `python3-flake8` (on Ubuntu) are installed.

Answer (score 1):

Only I did to fix this was to do:

```
  let g:syntastic_python_flake8_exec = '/path/to/python3'
```

To make sure flake8 is synced with Python3's syntax.
Even when I'm in a virtualenv works.

Answer (score 0):

Just to iterate on [Zaar Hai's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36865937/3314004) script a bit, something like this should work and be a bit more robust.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

_python=$(command -v python)

[[ "$(uname -s)" =~ Darwin ]] && IS_OSX=true

if [[ "$IS_OSX" ]]; then
    if command -v 'greadlink' >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        greadlink -f "$_python"
    else
        echo 'Install coreutils!' >&2
    fi
else
    readlink -f "$_python"
fi
```