# PyLint: No name 'new file' in module 'main_app'

Tags: python, django, pylint

I created a file (permissions.py) in the main app(main_app). Now I imported it to an actual app view (actual_app):

```
from main_app.permissions import SomeClass
```

Pylint is throwing errors:

```
E0611: No name 'permissions' in module 'main_app' (no-name-in-module)
E0401: Unable to import 'main_app.permissions' (import-error)
```

However if I excluded E0611, E0401 in the error checking, my program works perfectly fine. Any idea on this?

Additional findings:
if I do:

```
from ..main_app.permissions import SomeClass
```

Lint success, but now the actual program fails. Seems that it cant import the module the django way.

Comment: Are you using virtual env? If you are using virtual environment, it could be that ```pylint``` is unable to 'see' the modules. 
More: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923090/pylint-doesnt-point-to-virtualenv-python

Comment: Yes I am. However, I think this is a pylint bug on django. I think it's checking how python naturally import files but in this case, django is automatically importing from apps instead of directory.

Comment: is there an `__init__.py` file in `main_app`?

Comment: @4140tm yes there is

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell whether you're having the same issue, but I encountered this as well.

When there is both a file `foo.py`, and a folder `foo`, pylint seems not to know which one to follow. Python itself is smart enough that if there is a file `foo/bar.py` with a class `baz`, `from foo.bar import baz` works fine.

But pylint seems to only look at `foo.py`, and complains if this doesn't contain something called `bar`.

A workaround is to rename your file `foo.py`. Although it's not really a solution, it gets working code without the pylint-warning.